# binarization of a stack of image by one threshold

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation, imagej, threshold

I am going to binarize all my images in a stack with a threshold number e.g. 1200 for all of my images.However, I could not find it. The features that are available maintain different values for different images. Does anybody can help me about it and tell me how to do that in imagej or MATLAB.

Thanks

Comment: ["`BW = imbinarize(I,T)` creates a binary image from image `I` using the threshold value `T`."](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imbinarize.html)

Comment: Thanks Beaker :)